# How to know the length of a music file?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know in advance the length of a music file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `AudioFileGetProperty` function for getting properties of an audio file, such as its length.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AVAudioPlayer class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) of the AVfoundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer;

myVariable = myPlayer.duration; //duration in seconds